# How to resolve the dependency hell in order to install matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dependencies, pip

I want to install `matplotlib` via `pip`. However, I run into circular issues and at certain point I got stuck. Running `pip` in the terminal produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3080, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3066, in _call_aside
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3093, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 651, in _build_master
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 952, in require
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 839, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==1.5.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I tried to fix this with `easy_install`, but it produced the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3080, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3066, in _call_aside
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3093, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 653, in _build_master
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 666, in _build_from_requirements
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 839, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools==3.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Running `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` says that I already have the newest version.

My OS is `Ubuntu 14.04`. I have tried many different approaches to fix the issue and probably ended up doing even further harm. I don't recall everything I did and how I ended up at this stage, so unfortunately cannot give further info.

My objective is to have `matplotlib` installed in the end and have a stable state of all my `python` related libraries. Any solution will work, so I don't mind reinstalling everything or whatever would fix the issue.

**UPDATE**

Running `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib` produces

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'matplotlib' as source package instead of 'python-matplotlib'
E: Unable to find a source package for matplotlib
```

Whereas `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` produces

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-matplotlib is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

However, `matplotlib` is still not found from `python`.

Comment: Have you considered working with `virtualenv`.?

Comment: I am not sure if it will make my life easier and is more like a workaround. I am not aware of how it works, but the project that I work on is mainly a `C` project and we use `python` for some fancy stuff, so I was hoping for some more general fix.

Comment: `virtualenv` can be used as a general fix too..comes handy if you have to distribute the software without people having to install all the required libraries and when you run the program on different machines. It is fairly simple to setup and use : https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide.html

Comment: I once had to make scripts run on machine without sudo access, did it with `virtualenv`..my two cents

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

This should install the dependecies that matplotlib needs via the Ubuntu package management system (because a lot of those dependencies are not trivial to install with `pip`), enabling you to:

```
 pip install matplotlib
```

Source: [Matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#building-on-linux)

I have used this process on both Ubuntu 14.04 and Kubuntu 15.10 to install the newest, stable matplotlib (in virtual environments, but that shouldn't make a difference).

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. See my edit.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right Python installation to look for matplotlib? According to the `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` command it should be installed, but maybe you're using not the system Python, but some custom install, which can't find packages of the system Python. Try `which python` (should be /usr/bin/python for system Python).

Comment: Yes, I assumed the same. `which python` returns indeed `/usr/bin/python`, so I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Open the system Python console (`/usr/bin/python`) and try `help('modules')`. If you can't see matplotlib there despite being told that it's installed and despite using the system Python I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It doesn't. I asked another question to clear that out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348123/why-doesnt-ubuntu-install-matplotlib-for-my-correct-python-version