# Why doesn't Ubuntu install matplotlib for my correct python version?

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

When I type in `which python` I get `/usr/bin/python` as expected. However, I wanted to install `matplotlib` and running `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-matplotlib is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Fair enough, I thought that the library was installed, but when I tried to import it I got an error:

```
[ivaylo@ivaylo-K55VD ~]$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr 24 2015, 12:56:53) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
>>>
```

So it turns out I have `matplotlib` installed for my default implementation, yet it cannot be found. I checked the contents of `/usr/bin/` and there are multiple python executables:

- `python` refers to, as you can see, version `2.7.9` and is the only version where `matplotlib` is not available.
- `python2` `python2.7` and `python2.7.6` all map to version `2.7.6` and there the library is available.
- `python3` and `python3.4` map to version `3.4.3` where `matplotlib` is also available, but only after I installed it with `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib`.

So my question is, why is the default `python` 2.7.9 and why doesn't apt install the library for the correct version?

My Ubuntu is `14.04` if that matters.

Comment: The "normal" python2 on ubuntu 14.04 is 2.7.6, (which can explain why  python-matplotlib works only with it) and I thought 2.7.9 could only be installed manually. Is it a personal computer ?

Comment: 2.7.6 is the default, default python for Ubuntu 14.04. Maybe you changed that at some point.

Comment: @polku, yes it is a personal computer. Probably I have changed it at some point. Any ideas on how I can turn it back? I know I can manually link it to 2.7.6 but what's the most proper way to do that?

Comment: How about using easy_install or pip?

Comment: @Phlya, I had some problems with those approaches.

Comment: Well, in my experience pip is the least problematic approach...

Comment: The proper way would be to undo whatever you did to put 2.7.9 there in the first place. If you used `update-alternatives`, then use that to revert the state. If you removed manually the link, then do so (again). If you want to go to the nuclear path, maybe try `apt-get install --reinstall python`. But a valid answ would need a little more of history regarding your scenario.